# How to push certain strings from an huge string into array

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native, fetch

This might sound weird, but i want to parse a xml response by pushing certain string with following regular expression:

```
data-href="[\d\w\/:\.\=]*[">]?
```

into an array.

The reason for this is just for testing. A friend has built a webpage with jimdo where he displays a image gallery. now i want to try parsing the xml on this site and only fetch the images which are at every data-href tag and use them in my react native app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the String.match method?

```
var matches = xml_str.match(/data-href="[\d\w\/:\.\=]*[">]?/g);
```

Edit: if you want to just get the URL within the href, use regex capture groups:

```
var matches = xml_str.match(/data-href="([\d\w\/:\.\=]*)[">]?/g);
console.log(matches);
```

You can then map the matches array to only contain the element with the URL.

Comment: Thanks mate. But i am doing something wrong in my code. If i test the xml response with https://regex101.com/ it looks great, but if i do this in my code i get a weird match response. Maybe it is correct, but how would u push every "data-href" in the response into a array?

Comment: Sorry, you have to put a global flag after the end delimiter in JS. I updated my answer. If you're still having trouble, save and post your regex101 link so I can check it out.

Comment: Thanks bro. It works here ```https://regex101.com/r/c3yiYX/2```, but not in my code. I get null in my code now

Comment: thanks mate. i updated by removing /d and then i just saw that i am not allowed to use the regEx in a string which i should have seen before!!! ```.match(/data-href="([\d\w\/:\.\=]*)[">]?/g);``` not ```.match("/data-href="([\d\w\/:\.\=]*)[">]?/g");```

Comment: @BigPun86—yes you can, just quote the quotes, e.g. `.match(/data-href=\"([\w\/:\.\=]*)[\">]?/g);`. Posting code as a runnable snippet helps ensure that it actually works. ;-)